# Factory of parameterized generic type class

Tags: c#

Figure out a class like:

```
class C<T> {}
```

I'd like to create some kind of factory in order to create unlimited `C<specific T>` implementations. So:

```
class Factory
{
    C<?> create(Type type)
    {
        return (C<?>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(C)).MakeGenericType(type));
    }
}
```

Is that possible?

How could I get that?

Comment: No this is not possible. You surely can´t write a compile-time method for a parameter which you know at runtime, can you?

Comment: Hovewer you can declare create() as returning 'object' type and make a cast in calling method.

Comment: Not to belabor the obvious, but are you sure you don't want `create<T>` instead? If you only know the type parameter at runtime, there's little point to having a generic class in the first place, since clients can't make use of any type information.